# Git clone taking forever to execute

Tags: git, gerrit

I am using Gerrit-GIT setup and trying to clone the git repository using http protocol. It works for 5-10mins after restarting my unix server. but hangs again.

But its taking forever to operate and I did not get any error on the UI.

Please suggest what can be checked here?

Just an FYI- I had increased my server root space 3 days back.

Comment: Take a look in the Gerrit log at GERRIT_SITE/logs/error_log

Comment: Check if you have some big files ( around 1 Gb) committed already or someone else. If yes it slows down git clone operation and all other git operations also.